# How to search for a fhir by identifier?

Tags: rest, search, full-text-search, identifier, hl7-fhir

I notice most if not all fhir resource types have a property 'identifier', which is of type identifier.
I have a **patient resource with an identifier of value:8270970042**, and I want to find them. I am using fhir r4.
I have set this on my resources to have a value, I'm wondering how I now search for resources with a given identifier?
I am facing an issue when I run this API it show me 500 internal server error.

Comment: this is the url wchich i want to run [link]({{base_url}}/kaiemr/api/fhir/r4/clinic/Patient?identifier=8270970042)

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers usually have a 'system' and are searched for using tokens.

[link]({{base_url}}/kaiemr/api/fhir/r4/clinic/Patient?identifier=8270970042|system=http://myindentifiernamespace.

Please refer to token search here: https://build.fhir.org/search.html#token

Comment: I also applied this but its not working

Comment: are you testing on a public test server? also can you share the system url for the name space. Also could be worth ensuring the Patient does exist on the server and the server does support an identifier search.